# XHPROF Error in the GUI. The ID remains to "-1"

Tags: php, xhprof

I am currently testing XHPROF (*wamp, windows xp*), with this code:

```
<? Php
xhprof_enable (XHPROF_FLAGS_CPU | XHPROF_FLAGS_MEMORY);

function bar ($ x) {
  if ($ x> 0) {
    bar ($ x - 1);
  }
}

function foo () {
  for ($ idx = 0; $ idx <5; $ idx + +) {
    bar ($ idx);
    $ X = strlen ("abc");
  }
}

/ / Run program
foo ();

/ / Stop profiling
= $ Xhprof_data xhprof_disable ();

/ / Display raw data xhprof for the profiling run
print_r ($ xhprof_data);


/ / $ XHPROF_ROOT = realpath (dirname (__FILE__). '/ ..');
XHPROF_ROOT $ = 'D: \ wamp \ offline-shared \ includes \ xhprof \ git \ xhprof';
/ / Include_once $ XHPROF_ROOT. "/ Xhprof_lib / utils / xhprof_lib.php";
/ / Include_once $ XHPROF_ROOT. "/ Xhprof_lib / utils / xhprof_runs.php";

Xhprof_root $ = 'D :/ wamp / offline-shared / includes / xhprof / git / xhprof /';
include_once $ xhprof_root. "Xhprof_lib / config.php";
include_once $ xhprof_root. "Xhprof_lib / utils / xhprof_lib.php";
include_once $ xhprof_root. "Xhprof_lib / utils / xhprof_runs.php";

/ / Save raw data for this profiling run using default
/ / Implementation of iXHProfRuns.
Xhprof_runs XHProfRuns_Default $ = new ();

/ / Save the run Under a namespace "xhprof_foo"
$ = $ Run_id xhprof_runs-> save_run ($ xhprof_data, "xhprof_foo");

echo "<a href='http://localhost/tests/xhprof/xhprof_html/index.php?run={$run_id}&source=xhprof_foo'> here </ a> topics:";
echo "<a href='http://xhprof-local/index.php?run={$run_id}&source=xhprof_foo'> and / or here </ a>";
```

So far, nothing fancy, but in the xhprofGUI (with  link(s) above, I get this error with the id remains to "-1":

```
Warning: gzuncompress () [ function.gzuncompress]: data error in D: \ wamp \ offline-shared \ includes \ xhprof \ git \ xhprof \ xhprof_lib \ utils \ xhprof_runs.php on line 278
Given XHProf Run not found.
```

and I get this error if I pass **not** by a  virtualhost with warnings:

```
Run Report
    Run # -1: Invalid Run Id = -1
```

An idea?
Thank you
Fabrice

Comment: Something seems to be really wrong with your php code. :o

Answer (score 0):

No, the php code is correct. I've found the answer. The sql CREATE statment is wrong. You must use the one located in the "Pdo.php" file.

And so, all is good :)

Fabrice